# Adding or reading some of the contact fields in symbian using j2me

Tags: java, symbian, java-me

I want to add or read the fields of contact like i am getting the telephone home no
`ContactList clist;`

`Contact con;`

`String no;`



`if(cList.isSupportedAttribute(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_HOME)) {`

    `con.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_HOME, no);`

`}`

and mobile no

`if(cList.isSupportedAttribute(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_MOBILE)) {`
    `con.addString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_MOBILE, mb);`
`}`

now i want to get the fields internet telephone, push to talk, mobile(home), mobile(business), dtmf, shareview, sip, children, spouse and some more fields

please help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of standard contact field and attributes you can use can be found at [Forum Nokia](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-654A42A3-C453-411A-A153-366C08AEF058/javax/microedition/pim/Contact.html) (since you're using a Symbian phone).

The JSR-75 specification doesn't really prevent handset manufacturers from adding more fields and attributes but you may need to write code to discover what is possible with your handset.

I would suggest filling a contact with as much information as you can using the handset embedded native Contact application first.

The useful methods for field and attribute discovery are:
`PIMList.getArrayElementLabel()`
`PIMList.getAttributeLabel()`
`PIMList.getFieldLabel()`
`PIMList.getSupportedArrayElements()`
`PIMList.getSupportedAttributes()`
`PIMList.getArrayElementLabel()`
`PIMList.getArrayElementLabel()`
`PIMList.getSupportedFields()`